# How can I update an Excel workbook from a scheduled SSIS package?

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package that imports data, then needs to update an Excel workbook for emailing. The Excel workbook contains a number of data connections set to auto refresh on open.

I have tried a number of ways to open the Excel workbook to force a refresh before emailing, and they all work when I run the package from Visual Studio, but don't work when invoked by the SQL Server agent.

Using [this code](http://jessicammoss.blogspot.com/2008/10/manipulating-excel-spreadsheets-in-ssis.html) from Jessica Moss, I get this error

```
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)
```

Using the [SSIS Excel Refresh Task package](https://ssisexcelrefresh.codeplex.com/) from codeplex I get this error

```
The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x800A03EC 
(Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '[my filename]')
```

Using a [powershell update script](https://superuser.com/questions/232656/how-do-you-update-an-excel-file-data-refresh-and-update-formulas-without-openi) I get this error.

```
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)
```

The agent is executing via proxy account with all the necessary permissions.
Excel is installed on the server.

How can I get the workbook to update when running from the SQL server agent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the system profile directory

```
%windir%\System32\config\systemprofile
```

Create a folder called `desktop`

Now the Excel workbook will update using any of the above methods.

Comment: Why would this work?  Why does this not work for me?  See my error here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537847/package-execution-issue-when-run-as-sql-agent-works-from-ssidb-ssis-powershell